# How to infer missing values in a R data frame from other rows that have the data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In my example I have a table with products that have a unique ID in Store 1 and a different (but also unique) ID in Store 2.

As a rule, the same product has always the same ID in store 1 and always the same ID in store 2. i.e. if I know only one of these variables, I should be able to fill in the remaining ones.

However, I don't have a neat reference table or list that shows which Product and IDs belong together. All I have to start with is a table with lots of gaps like this:

[image: Before]

I would like to fill the gaps using the information that is already in the table like so:

[image: After]

Is there a R function that can do this or how would you go about this?

```
#Example data
df <- data.frame(
  c(NA, "Shovel", NA, NA, "Gloves", NA),
  c("W06", NA, "W06", "W11", "W11", NA),
  c("EF001", "EF001", NA, NA, "EF004", "EF004")
)
colnames(df) <- c("Product", "Store1_ID", "Store2_ID")


df2 <- data.frame(
  c("Shovel",NA, NA, NA, "Gloves", NA),
  c(NA, "W06", "W06", "W11", "W11", NA),
  c("EF001", "EF001", NA, NA, "EF004", "EF004")
)
colnames(df2) <- c("Product", "Store1_ID", "Store2_ID")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update II: For the new dataset `df2`:

add the .direction argument to fill in both direction the grouping variable and then apply the fill_run funciton:

```
library(dplyr)
library(runner)

df2 %>% 
  fill(Store1_ID, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  group_by(Store1_ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~fill_run(., run_for_first = TRUE)))
```

```
  Product Store1_ID Store2_ID
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    
1 Shovel  W06       EF001    
2 Shovel  W06       EF001    
3 Shovel  W06       EF001    
4 Gloves  W11       EF004    
5 Gloves  W11       EF004    
6 Gloves  W11       EF004
```

**Update** to consider groupwise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(runner)

df %>% 
  fill(Store1_ID) %>% 
  group_by(Store1_ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~fill_run(., run_for_first = TRUE)))
```

```
   Product Store1_ID Store2_ID
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    
1 Shovel  W06       EF001    
2 Shovel  W06       EF001    
3 Shovel  W06       EF001    
4 Gloves  W11       EF004    
5 Gloves  W11       EF004    
6 Gloves  W11       EF004
```

Comment: .direction = "updown" seems to do the trick. The downside is that I still need to pick a column first (Store1_ID), and I am not sure if this will work in situations where I have different column headers. Nonetheless, this solved my problem for now and I accepted this answer because I find it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Create a grouping index column, after looping `across` the 'Store' columns, apply the `na.locf0` to replace the `NA` elements with previous non-NA values, if there are NAs as beginning element, then apply the `na.locf0` with `fromLast = TRUE` on top of the first `na.locf0`, convert this to logical column with `duplicated`, negate (`!`) so that it returns TRUE for first non-duplicated element and FALSE for others, get the cumulative sum (`cumsum`), use `pmax` to find the max index elementwise to create the 'grp', then we use `fill` on the other columns

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = invoke(pmax, across(starts_with('Store'), 
    ~ cumsum(!duplicated(zoo::na.locf0(zoo::na.locf0(.x), 
           fromLast = TRUE))), .names = "{.col}_new")))  %>% 
 fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
 ungroup %>% 
 select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Product Store1_ID Store2_ID
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    
1 Shovel  W06       EF001    
2 Shovel  W06       EF001    
3 Shovel  W06       EF001    
4 Gloves  W11       EF004    
5 Gloves  W11       EF004    
6 Gloves  W11       EF004
```

- The `.names` is used to create a new column, though in this case, it is not needed

Same output with `df2`

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(grp = invoke(pmax, across(starts_with('Store'), 
    ~ cumsum(!duplicated(zoo::na.locf0(zoo::na.locf0(.x), 
     fromLast = TRUE))), .names = "{.col}_new"))) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Product Store1_ID Store2_ID
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    
1 Shovel  W06       EF001    
2 Shovel  W06       EF001    
3 Shovel  W06       EF001    
4 Gloves  W11       EF004    
5 Gloves  W11       EF004    
6 Gloves  W11       EF004
```